# C# multiple entry points in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

Program.cs is my main file and main method within is the entry point for my application. I have 2 other files, **file1.cs** and **file2.cs**.Both classes have its own string that I want to output using the Console.WriteLine function. When I run the program.cs file the output from the 2 other files dont show. If I run the code separately adding **static void Main(string[] args)** then it works.

I tried changing the name of the methods as well but no success. I also tried importing the namespaces in the program.cs file.

```
using File1;
using File2;
```

Can anyone provide some guidance or docs that could help me ?Thanks

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome User");
        }
    }
}
```

file1.cs

```
namespace File1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is string 1");
        }
    }
}
```

file2.cs

```
namespace File2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is string 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A console program can only have 1 main entry point

Comment: The operating system can't magically know what you want ,hence one entry point .... so, what are the rules here

Comment: I understand that there can only be 1 main method / entry point. Should I then just rename the methods in the 2 files ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to call the methods from `program.cs` ro be able to run those. Something like this:

```
using System;

namespace MyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome User");
            File1.Program.Main(args);
            File2.Program.Main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

And you should make `Program` class as static too on File1 and File2